# Completely disable mouse selection in IDEA/Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ideavim

I'm using the IdeaVim plugin for Android Studio, which introduces vim selection semantics and insert/normal mode. When there is a selection, something akin to visual mode is used. However, it is possible to select text while inside either of these modes, and the result is some hybrid insert-visual mode which is highly confusing and leads me to tons of accidental edits (i.e. clicking an editable area sometimes puts me in a mode I don't understand).

If I could completely disable mouse selection (using mouse only to select text, like `set mouse=ni`), it would make the editor much more comfortable, as this is my preferred vim selection mechanic.

There seems to be no standard option for disabling mouse selection. Is some modification feasible?

I still need to be able to select text using IdeaVim visual mode, i.e. `v` followed by cursor keys.

Comment: What are the situations when mouse selection results in a mode different from the standard Vim visual mode? Please describe them in more detail. I would prefer to fix the visual mode rather than to disable the mouse.

Comment: I haven't understood all the situations (because I mostly panic), but one such is this: enter insert mode, select some text with mouse. Now there is a visual selection and you are apparently in visual mode but the cursor represents insert mode (bar rather than block). Pressing escape now takes you to insert mode in the new location, rather than normal mode.

Comment: Anothing thing that happens is I accidentally select a bit of text when I'm use the mouse to click to pick a split window section. I then think I'm in normal mode (because I'm used to vim with `set mouse=n`) and move around with `0` and `hjkl` and get an unwanted visual selection in addition to my movement.